# Get the data from barcode scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm building web application for fitness center, they have a barcode scanner to which you are scanning your gym card into. What i'm trying to accomplish is to somehow get the data that the scanner is providing to them (name,surname and time of monthly subscription). My web application is built in ASP.NET C#, this is my first time dealing with this kind of problem.
I would appreciate your help or any other word of advice, feel free to ask more detailed questions.

Comment: Don't expect to get the data (name, surname and time of monthly subscription) from scanning the membership card, what you will most likely get is a user id, then you will fetch the data from a DB. For the scanner to work with the webpage, you can look at https://github.com/schmich/instascan

Answer (score 1):

If gym has barcode scanner like this [image]
, it is seen in the system as a keyboard.
Such a scanner should also be able to set the ending character `Tab` or `Enter`. You do not need to confirm the scanned code then.
A card with a barcode as above returns the card number associated with a given person in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have access to the barcode scanner from MVC (Core or Framework). To do that you would probably have to run some software on the computer or phone that is scanning the member cards. There might be a solution though since the barcode scanner might be able to copy the id. This way you could input it to an input field in your MVC application and post it to the backend from there.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your Question correctly you probably need a SerialPort.

its actually pretty easy..

```
SerialPort serPort = new SerialPort("COM7"); // thats the USB port on which the scanner is connected
serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
serPort.Open();
```

and now you will receive everythig the Scanner has on:

```
private void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
   
   string response = serPort.ReadExisting();

   //do work
}
```

also if u dont know which port it is connected on use :

```
 foreach (string sp in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            port = new SerialPort(sp)
            {
                Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
            };
            port.DataReceived += new 
            SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
            port.Open();
        }
```

this will watch over every Port you have see if something is connected and opens a connection to it, obviously if u have something like a mobile phone connected it will open a port with it too. but you can just make a check that if u scan u will only take that port and so on..

IF i did understand your question correctly that u want to know how to communicate with the Scanner thats how you do it.

if that was not your question, please comment and Clarify im working all day with Mobile Scanners Reading Barcodes so i think i will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all handheld barcode scanners have a barcode in it's manual to change the scanner to function as a keyboard wedge. This way the scanner functions exactly like a keyboard device. You'd scan a barcode and keycodes are sent to the cursor location.

So just look up the make/model of your scanner and download its manual and look for a barcode that you can scan to change its emulation mode.